# Get to session variable by ajax call

Tags: php, symfony, session

I am going to set a session variable called sliderhash in a controller called Main. In symfony2 I see the session variable and it is going to be set alright. If I do now make an ajax call, I cant't get to the session variable. How can I solve this problem?

MainController.php

```
MainController {...

public function setSessionAction() {
....
$session = $request->getSession();
$session->set('sliderhash', '1234');
```

AnalyticsController.php

```
AnalyticsController {...

public function piccounterAction(Request $request) {
    $request->getSession();
    $session->get('sliderhash'); //always returns NULL
```

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()` in your AJAX page?

Comment: Does the setSessionAction method ever get called?

Comment: @Machavity. What do you mean?

Comment: Of course it is going to be called

Comment: Okay, if I am going make GET instead of POST, I can get to my session variable. Why?

Comment: Are you requesting slightly different URLs (i.e. www and non-www), or setting on dev but reading on prod (or vice versa). If you can read on GET but not POST, what's the difference in URLs/headers in the network tab on your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Trying to set session in the same page that has the Ajax was always prone to error for me. If you go to a second page maybe you can see it. Try it. I wanted to do this too, but I the end passed the variables in the ajax call parameters.